# Magento 2.3.3 An error occured on the server, and nosuchentityexception on checkout

Tags: error, onepage-checkout, magento2.3.3, no-such-entity-exception

I have this problem with the magento checkout, when placing an order the first try will return an error, but the second will work.
the error is

> A server error stopped your order from being placed. Please try to
>   place your order again.
>
> "trace":"#0
>   /home/uhdcusr/httpdocs/cr-store/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Checkout\Model\PaymentInformationManagement->savePaymentInformationAndPlaceOrder(147...

and also a critical log is thrown in exceptions.log

```
[2020-01-14 20:19:22] main.CRITICAL: DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (15/01/2020 00:00) at position 0 (1): Unexpected character {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 0): DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (15/01/2020 00:00) at position 0 (1): Unexpected character at /app/vendor/magento/framework/Stdlib/DateTime.php:58)"} []
[2020-01-14 20:20:53] main.CRITICAL: Aucune entité avec customerId = 120 {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\NoSuchEntityException(code: 0): Aucune entité avec customerId = 120 at /app/vendor/magento/framework/Exception/NoSuchEntityException.php:50)"} []
```

the exception is thrown in **PaymentInformationManagement** in **savePaymentInformationAndPlaceOrder**

```
 $this->savePaymentInformation($cartId, $paymentMethod, $billingAddress);
    try {
        $orderId = $this->cartManagement->placeOrder($cartId);
    } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
        throw new CouldNotSaveException(
            __($e->getMessage()),
            $e
        );
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $this->getLogger()->critical($e);
        throw new CouldNotSaveException(
            __('A server error stopped your order from being placed. Please try to place your order again.'),
            $e
        );
    }
```

and the critical log is in **model/Session** at **getQuote**

i found an issue on github https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/23411
but they only talked about the critical log not the checkout error.
any ideas or help will be really appreciated. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Kames, you Can find the solution at

https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/25307/files

Or you can try below solution

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/23411#issuecomment-516611919

You have to apply the changes to respective files.

Comment: thanx for your answer but these solutions address the critical log issue not the checkout error issue. if you're sure that it can fix the server error issue tell me how to apply this fix without changing the magento core files.thanx again.